# Как привязать к точке на изображении другое изображение

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

ищу либу или подсказки в какую сторону копать, чтобы получить на выходе практически вот это https://github.com/timseverien/taggd, но вместо текста к точке надо будет привязать несколько фотографий, сделать мини галлерею, наподобие яндекс/гугл карт, когда в любой точке карты можно посмотреть панорамные фото местности

Comment: а что мешает код библиотеки глянуть?

Comment: я новичок в js и плохо понимаю тамошний код, мне бы название технологий которые там надо использовать и я тогда смогу погуглить нормально и изучить это

Comment: у вас будет использоваться карта от гугл или яндекса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
document.getElementById("bg").onclick = function(e){
  var imageUrl = prompt("Введите ссылку на изображение:");
  if ( imageUrl ){
    /* Создаем изображение */
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imageUrl;
    img.style.position = "absolute";
    img.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
    img.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
    /* Создаем точку */
    var point = document.createElement("div");
    point.classList.add("point");
    point.style.top = e.pageY - 5 + "px";
    point.style.left = e.pageX - 5 + "px";
    /* Добавляем созданные объекты на карту*/
    document.getElementById("bg").appendChild(point);
    document.getElementById("bg").appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

```css
#bg {
  background: url('https://www.vsyaotdelka.ru/upload/iblock/b7c/b7c0eaf40b5d4010ebc1f16ebe0a73ca.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.point {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 0.5em; 
}
```

```html
<div id="bg" style="">
</div>

<div id="hint"></div>
```

Так - изучайте CSS, JavaScript и смотрите в сторону библиотеки [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

**UPD:** Обновил код с использованием изображения. Для закрытия изображения просто кликните по нему.

**UPD 2:** Обновил еще раз код. Для его работы нужно кликнуть по карте и в появившемся запросе указать путь к изображению, например *http://server.com/..../image.jpg*

Comment: мне нужно чтобы к точке привязывались фотографии и чтобы это мог делать пользователь сайта

Comment: @123jsnew, обновил код. Пользователь сайта может кликать по точкам.

Comment: Ответ хороший, но вот совет по поводу jQuery удручает. Не надо смотреть в ее сторону, лучше ванилу вначале понять, а потом понять, что жквери в 2018 уже не нужен

Comment: @Kosmos я имел в виду, чтобы пользователь мог сам создавать на изображении эту точку и привязывать к ней фотографии. для примера https://www.structionsite.com/ к чертежу пользователь прикрепляет панорамное фото  в любой точке

Comment: @123jsnew, это уже другая задача. В целом, лучше сразу точно описывать что именно вам нужно, чтобы не вводить других в заблуждение.

Comment: @Kosmos извиняюсь если ввел в заблуждение, а по данной задаче могли бы дать наводку?

Comment: @123jsnew, обновил еще раз код. Для его работы нужно кликнуть по карте и в появившемся запросе указать путь к изображению, например *http://server.com/..../image.jpg*

Comment: @Kosmos благодарю, это уже похоже на правду. А как сделать, чтобы прикрепленное к точке изображение свертывалось, а не висело постоянно

Comment: @123jsnew, в целом, добавить обработчик типа document.getElementsByTagName("img").onclick = function(){
  this.style.visibility = "hidden";
};

Comment: @Kosmos благодарю вас! очень помогли!